# Invoking an Ant Target Programmatically in an Intellij/IDEA plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to invoke an ant target based on a user action within a plugin. Doing this used to work:

```
AntConfiguration conf = AntConfiguration.getInstance(project);
```

My `plugin.xml` contains the entry:

```
<depends optional="false">AntSupport</depends>
```

As mentioned [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206777255-Issues-with-accessing-AntConfiguration?page=1#community_comment_206155495).

However, with the current version of IntelliJ it throws this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.intellij.lang.ant.config.impl.AntConfigurationImpl cannot be cast
>   to com.intellij.lang.ant.config.AntConfiguration  at
>   com.intellij.lang.ant.config.AntConfiguration.getInstance(AntConfiguration.java:38)
>     at
>   com.codename1.plugin.intellij.ant.AntRunner.getAntFile(AntRunner.java:133)
>     at
>   com.codename1.plugin.intellij.ant.AntRunner.runTarget(AntRunner.java:59)
>     at
>   com.codename1.plugin.intellij.actions.CodenameOneAction.runAntTarget(CodenameOneAction.java:61)
>     at
>   com.codename1.plugin.intellij.actions.SendAndroidBuild.actionPerformed(SendAndroidBuild.java:17)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:191)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

This looks like a bug to me but I might be misusing the API in some way as this isn't quite "documented" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured this one out. I neglected to set the library dependency to provided state and had them at "compiled" state. This was somewhat hidden in the dependency window:

[image]